# accessing a network drive programmatically on ios

Tags: ios, ipad, network-programming

Is it possible to access a network drive with ios dev?

I'm looking for a way to access to a network drive and be able to browse within it or pick file from it.

Otherwise is it possible to access to a network shared directory?

Answer (score 0):

What file system is used on the network drive? How do you access it currently or is this a new application?

Can you access it using WebDAV? If so, see https://github.com/ccgus/flycode/tree/master/WebDAV for an example for iOS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.This is a new application. What i'm trying to do is to insert the network drive address in a textFiel, browse on it and pick a file from it. I'm also precising that i'm very new on iphone/ipad dev (some of question might be stupid, sorry for that).

Comment: So, what file system is your network drive? What protocol do you wish to use?

Comment: Hi @Pål Brattberg , at first i intended to use windows shared directory but i end up using tomcat as a web server that gives me the contains of the directory. Also, i was completely lost about file shared protocols and stuff. Anyway, thank you so much for taking the time to answer me.